# Authorization of amazon account on fire tv

Tags: android, amazon-clouddrive

I want to authorize amazon account on fire tv. for this i follow the steps in following url [Getting starting with amazon cloud drive API's](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/getting-started) but when i make urls and want to open in web view(as fire tv has no browser) it gives me error

> your redirect_uri is not whitelisted

but i have already whitelist my app kindly give me suggession to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you whitelist your client_id to access the Amazon Cloud Drive API, which is mentioned in the Registering Your App section of [Getting Started with Amazon Cloud Drive API](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/getting-started)?